# analogic accusative endings on pronouns?

Tags: indo-european, cases

Do accusative ‘me’ and ‘thee’ have final /m/ (or evidence of a lost or altered /m/), by analogy with (non-neuter) nouns, **in any Indo-European language**?

Comment: Absolutely. Some languages, most well-known them Sanskrit [अहम](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/अहम्) _ahám_ and [त्वम](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/त्वम्) _tvám_ even went so far as to analogically add an m to the nominative form as well (at least in _tvám_ – the m in _ahám_ is probably something else).

Comment: (… “most well-known **among** them”, of course)

Answer (score 1):

"me" and "thee" never had a final "m". The Proto Indoeuropean accusative forms were simply "hme" and "te".
(Different reconstructions see [here](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Reconstruction:Proto-Indo-European/%C3%A9%C7%B5h%E2%82%82))

In Latin, the vowel was lengthened: mē, tē.
Indoiranian added an "m".
Proto Germanic added a "k" in the accusative case, a "z" in the dative case.

The source of the final "k" is either from the particle "ge" which still existed in Ancient Greek, or comes from the nominative "heg" (Proto-Germanic ik, German ich, Enlish I).

The modern English forms "me/thee", however, might rather derive from the dative forms "miz/þiz" which the odd ending "z". The Proto Indoeuropean Dative was "tebhi/toi" or something like this. The Germanic formation is unique here.

See [here](https://books.google.de/books?id=CBAUDAAAQBAJ&pg=PA211&lpg=PA211&dq=miz%20%C3%BEiz%20proto%20germanic%20%22z%22&source=bl&ots=OHniSk7bfV&sig=ACfU3U1fteK9Pea4k4BnHNXVHEnjC-XcJw&hl=de&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjQ-IuPvob3AhWJhP0HHVHrABUQ6AF6BAgwEAM#v=onepage&q=miz%20%C3%BEiz%20proto%20germanic%20%22z%22&f=false).

Comment: This doesn’t actually answer the question asked, except in the one brief note that IIr. added an _-m_ (which makes the answer “yes”). I think you may have misread the question.

Comment: I misread the question the same way: I thought the question was about the English words _me_ and _thee_.